# tf.train.Server.create_local_server has two problems :1)performance drop 2 times compare to without it,2) gpu memory fraction limitations fails

Tags: tensorflow

`tf.train.Server.create_local_server` has two problems

1)performance drop 2 times compare to without it

2) gpu memory fraction limitations fails

code1: without `server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server(start = True)`

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)

sess =  tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True,allow_soft_placement=True,gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

code2:  `using server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server(start = True)`

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)

    server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server(start = True)

    sess= tf.Session(target=server.target,config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True,allow_soft_placement=True,gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

Questions:

1. code2 performance drop 2 times compare to code1( 3 steps/seconds vs 11 steps/seconds), why?
2. code2 will broke the  limitations of gpu memory. while code1 is ok
3. is this has the same phenomenon in the tensorflow distribution？

ps: Is this relevant to this issue than the training data is read from queue?